# Creating Windows Partition and Dual Boot from Stand Alone Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Ok after a few days of searching with no luck, not even help from the volunteers at boot-repair techs. I've decided to post on here and youtube. Here's my situation:
Acer Aspire V5-122P
1.0 Ghz AMD A4
4GB RAM 
500GB HDD
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
3.13.0-61-generic

This is currently not a dual-boot but I am trying to set it up as such.
I have paritioned 400GB of hard disk space for Windows (unformatted).
I've been having trouble getting past the Windows Splash screen when trying to install the OS. I'm no expert with EFI and boot managers.

I can't post images but if you need a screen shot of what my GParted looks like I can send one, or screen shots of anything that could be helpful.

Link to boot-repair

[Troubleshoot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11991475/)

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the **people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows**, but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: Ok, thank you. I can dual boot from Windows and adding Ubuntu. But in this particular case I can't figure out how to add Windows from Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm sorry for the canned comment above: Asking about Windows makes your question **off-topic** here...  Sorry!  **:-/**

Comment: You should only have one efi partition per device. Remove boot flag from sda5. If a BIOS install with MBR(msdos) it would be correct to have boot flag on NTFS partition. But with UEFI, the boot flag is only on ESP - efi system partition. Then Windows may see the NTFS as NTFS. Be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thank you oldfred, I didn't notice that so I fixed that flag and followed the commands below. Thanks for the help and input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to add Windows from Ubuntu?  I assume you mean to the boot menu.

Run this in Terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda; sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed lol. It was so difficult finding a simple two line command that could fix all my problems. And I did have two boot flags I noticed. Thanks again :)